# Assign realm role to service account keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a service account in `master` realm. from `admin-cli` I want to assign the service account `master-realm-client` admin role. how can I do that.

```
kcadm.sh add-roles -r master --rolename admin --uusername master-realm-client
```

OR

```
kcadm.sh add-roles -r master --rolename admin --cclientid master-realm-client
```

is not working. kindly help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use below kcadm command for this

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh add-roles --uusername service-account-<CLIENT-ID> --rolename <ROLE-NAME> -r <REALM-NAME>
```

So it will be look like this

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh add-roles --uusername service-account-client --rolename adminRole -r master
```

Comment: can you please tell how to create an admin role for the client and give it permissions to create users in the realm

Comment: i created a role admin in my client. and assigned to it. but when i request the keycloak to create users it gives me 403 forbidden

Comment: Please ask a new question with full details .

Comment: can you please help here. I will create a detailed question to cover few more things. thanks

Comment: @Ahmed it's against SO policy,please ask diffrent question will definitely try to help.